# async function test with Observable.delay in Angular Unit test not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, observable

This is my mock Service and it is written with 10ms delay:

```
class MockHttp {   
  post(url, body, option): Observable<Response> {
    let resOpt = new ResponseOptions({
      body: JSON.stringify({success: true})
    });
    let res: Response = new Response(resOpt);
    return Observable.of(res).delay(10);
  }
}
```

And here is my test case.

```
it('http post should get valid response without any param', fakeAsync(() => {
    let retVal = null;
    // note this is just blackbox testing. httpHelperSerivce.post() function is wrapper of http.post(p1, p2, p3), 
    httpHelperService.post('url', {a: 'a'}).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      retVal = res;
    });
    tick();
    expect(retVal).toEqual({success: true});
    discardPeriodicTasks();
  }));
```

The test does not wait for delay. Without delay it works.

Is there anything wrong to my code? Delay on `MockHttp` is out of current zone?

Comment: Be aware that RxJS uses [`setInterval`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/scheduler/AsyncAction.ts#L40-L58) and not `setTimeout`, so if the former is not mocked that might explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything wrong with your test.

Try Observable.timer(10).map(() => res).take(1) instead of Observable.of(res).delay(10).

I also had some problems with rx's .delay() and jasmine.clock().tick() in the past